# Enter key reloads Chrome Browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a inputfield and an eventlistener keypress, in Firefox erverything is fine. If I run it in Chrome and hit the enter key the browser refreshes and the page is loaded again.

```
$('#iputField').keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var message = $('#iputField').val();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the form is submiting, you have to stop the default event propagation to avoid that.

```
$('#iputField').keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.which == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var message = $('#iputField').val();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try saying `e.preventDefault();` after the function ends.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a form, you probably need to call `e.preventDefault()`.

[Handling the "Enter" / "Return" key in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497133/handling-the-enter-return-key-in-chrome?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Try preventing the default behaviour:

```
 $('#iputField').keypress(function(e) {
     if(e.which == 13) {
        e.preventDefault().
        var message = $('#iputField').val();
     }
 });
```